# Creating a procedure (Error Code: 1064)

Tags: mysql, sql

Getting an error. I'm trying to procedure* a table and people have been telling me to put `DELIMITER $$` in, however, I'm still getting an error code #1064.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE test(test NUMBER NOT NULL)
END $$
```

Comment: You are not creating a table but a procudure .. is not the same  .. and  you  have a  sintax error   . (seems you don't have a procedure body   at the moment)

Comment: @scaisEdge, Ah. Sorry. Meant to say procedure.

Comment: You have an `END` but no `BEGIN`.  Plus, your procedure doesn't nothing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I know it does nothing. Yet. However, why is it giving me a 1064 error?

Comment: That is not valid MySQL syntax - MySQL does not have the "OR REPLACE" option. Also, in the documentation parts in square brackets tend to be optional & if used then you do not include the square brackets - so the command would be _"CREATE PROCEDURE ...."_ or _"CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ..."_   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html